# Array of functions to as argument in Golang

Tags: arrays, function

How can I pass an array of functions to my main function Validate?
I cant get the right syntax for this

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func upper(input string) string {

    return "hola"
}

func Validate(spec string, validations []func(string) string) {

    for err, exec := range validations {
        fmt.Println(exec(spec))
    }
}



func main() {
    Validate("Hola", []func{upper})
}
```

Regards!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is correct example of using slice arguments. Before using slice literal you need to specify it's type.

```
package main

import "fmt"

func upper(input string) string {
    return "hola"
}

func Validate(spec string, validations []func(string) string) {
    for _, exec := range validations {
        fmt.Println(exec(spec))
    }
}

func main() {
    Validate("Hola", []func(string) string{upper})
}
```